# Does importing libraries load everything in Arduino?

Tags: memory-management, embedded, arm, arduino, microcontroller

I am experimenting with an Arduino using various open source libraries written for Arduino. Most of those libraries have hundreds of methods/features but I am actually using a very few of them.

In such cases does the Arduino load everything to it's memory? In other words is there any advantage in extracting the required out of the library?

Further please point me to any good articles that describes the memory management in Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. It simply uses the libraries that you select with the #include statement. 
Since the memory in the arduino is limited you only load the required libraries, and once you compile them only the required functions get compiled into binary. so memory usage is minimum. 
Have a look at the memory model of the arduino http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memory , it is quite concise.

Comment: I have seen the placement of #include <..> wrapped around #ifdef (0) still get its RAM allocated. Presumably the pointers for its function. I am not sure how efficient the optimization used by the IDE. Hence something from an unused library is compiled in.

Answer (score 0):

A static-link library is a collection of object files in an archive.  The *linker* will search the library to resolve references in the code and will extract and link only those object files containing the code it needs to resolve such symbols.

How efficient this is depends on the *granularity* of the library.  For example, if all functions - even the ones you do not need - are defined in a single object file, then the linker will extract and link the entire object file, which can cause bloated code.  Ideally the library author will have defined one external interface (or at least interfaces that are always used together) per object file.

A smart linker can perform what is called *linker feedback*, where it essentially performs the link twice so that it can remove unreferenced code even within a single object file. I don't know whether your linker does that, but presumably the information will be in the documentation.

In any event, you can get the linker to generate a link map which will show you exactly what has been linked and how large it is.  Be aware of course that many library functions will have dependencies on further library functions, so code will be included that you may not have directly referenced in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can "avr-objdump -t" to create a map from your elf. And -d for an assembly listing. As to see it for your self. You need to enable show verbose output of compilation from the IDE's preferences, to display the temporary directory that contains the elf file.

example:

```
C:\DOCUME~1\mflaga\LOCALS~1\Temp\build6395515806682540138.tmp>C:\projects\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-objdump -t MP3Shield_Library_Demo.cpp.elf > MP3Shield_Library_Demo_wo_mem.cpp.elf.map
C:\DOCUME~1\mflaga\LOCALS~1\Temp\build6395515806682540138.tmp>C:\projects\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-objdump -d MP3Shield_Library_Demo.cpp.elf > MP3Shield_Library_Demo_wo_mem.cpp.elf.lst
```

I did the above and commented out a call to a function member of my library, between subsequent builds. To see that the code was not linked into the assembly.

Comment: I will need to go back and see why my above comment about #def'ed out libraries still use RAM.